# Primeng Calendar reloading page on select date

Tags: angular, calendar, href, primeng

I'm currently using this component from the new version 1.0.0 with angular 2.0.0-rc7 and when I click on any date, due to its href="#" the page got reloaded, a behavior I want to avoid.

[I was checking the source code on github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/2cd400e5fec41d549fc37c383c31aeb142b33725/components/calendar/calendar.ts), but didn't got any luck.

What could I do?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an angular problem. I updated Angular 2 to **2.2.2** and now it works fine.